# Moving items in an SWT tree from parent to parent

Tags: java, tree, swt

I want to move a `TreeItem` with all of its child nodes from one parent to another. But I found no method for that.

Is really the only way to do this by removing the `TreeItem` and rebuild it at the new position?

That would be quite time-consuming because my node can have a lot of children and/or subtrees so I have to make a recursion...

Comment: If you can use the JFace TreeViewer it is a bit easier with that since you only have to update the data model and then refresh the tree.

Comment: Hm, I'm still using pure SWT so I looked for a solution there. But nevertheless thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the parent of a `TreeItem` your only option is to dispose of the item at its original position and re-create the item with its new parent.

As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) mentioned, if you have a data model, you may want to use a `TreeViewer` which does the re-parenting for you.

Performancewise this isn't a problem, unless you have millions of items. But with such figures you would already run into performance problems while populating the tree initially.